# Check proof of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

> Suppose $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ are continuous at $a$ and $f(x)\leq g(x)\leq h(x)$ for $|x-a|<k$ if $f(a)=h(a)$ show that $g$ is continuous at $a$

Please check my proof:

Since $f(x)$ and is continuous at $a$ , and if $f(a)=h(a)$ we will have $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ has limit and

$$|f(x)-L|\leq g(x)\leq |h(x)-L|$$

by sandwich theorem $\lim g(x)=L $

since limit exist at $a$ then $g$ is continuous at $a$

Comment: Perhaps you want $|g(x)-L|$?

Comment: Basically, you proved nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch:

Since both $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $a$, for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$ with $|x-a|<\delta$, $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$ and $|h(x)-L|<\varepsilon$.

You can prove that $|g(x)-L|\leq\max\{|f(x)-L|,|h(x)-L|\}$.  Therefore, $|g(x)-L|<\varepsilon$.  This is the main error in your approach, the inequality that you write is not correct.

This proves that the limit of $g(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$ is $L$.  Since $f$ and $h$ are continuous, $L=f(a)\leq g(a)\leq h(a)=L$, so $g(a)=L$.  Therefore, $g(a)=L=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x)$.  Hence $g$ is continuous at $a$.